# Cauchy problem $u_x+xu_y=0$ and $u(x,0)=e^x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let u be a solution of the following PDE $u_x+xu_y=0$ and $u(x,0)=e^x$ then u(2,1) and u(-2,1)?
I did this by using Cauchy method, but I got stuck in sign having square root..

Comment: The initial value is incompatible with the level curves from the differential equation. The problem is invalid, but could be fixed if there was a typo or information missing (domain restrictions, other boundaries etc)

Comment: That was the exact question.

Comment: @NinadMunshi can you verify this answer?

Comment: What do you mean? Verify what?

Comment: Wether solution by @tom is correct or not?

Comment: Tom hasn't provided a solution per se, he explained in more detail that your problem is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{du}{dx} = u_x + u_y\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$
with $\frac{dy}{dx} = x$ is an equivalent formulation of the problem.

$$y = \frac{x^2}{2} + c_1, $$
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 0 \Rightarrow u = f(y-\frac{x^2}{2}) $$
At y=0:
$$u(x,0) = f(-\frac{x^2}{2}) = e^{x} \Rightarrow f(a) = exp(\pm(-2a)^{\frac{1}{2}})$$

For x>0:
$$u = f(y-\frac{x^2}{2}) = exp({(x^2-2y)^{\frac{1}{2}}})$$
For x<0:
$$u = f(y-\frac{x^2}{2}) = exp({-(x^2-2y)^{\frac{1}{2}}})$$
The problem is ill defined there must be another initial condition stating which side of x = 0 the system starts.